# How do I write my data along the columns in a CSV file?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

When I write to the csv file all of my data is printed in only the first column. Using my loop, how do I iterate along the columns to write the data?

```
import csv
import bs4
import urllib
from urllib.request import  urlopen as uReq
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

#For sites that can't be opened due to Urllib blocker, use a Mozilla User agent to get access
pageRequest = Request('https://coronavirusbellcurve.com/', headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
htmlPage = urlopen(pageRequest).read()
page_soup = soup(htmlPage, 'html.parser')
specificDiv = page_soup.find("div", {"class": "table-responsive-xl"})

TbodyStats = specificDiv.table.tbody.tr.contents
TbodyDates = specificDiv.table.thead.tr.contents


with open('CovidHTML.csv','w', newline= '') as file:
    theWriter = csv.writer(file)             
    theWriter.writerow(['5/4', ' 5/5', ' 5/6',' 5/7',' 5/8',' 5/9'])
    for i in range(3,len(TbodyStats)):
        if i%2 != 0:
            theWriter.writerow([TbodyStats[i].text])
```

Comment: Not able to tell without more information but in your for loop you might want to accumulate six items in a list then call `writerow` - probably use enumerate and  modulo six to know when to write a row and create a new empty list.  Your iteration could be simplified by using the step parameter of range - `range(3,len(TbodyStats),2)` then you won't need the `if`. - Or seems like you could just use `for thing in TbodyStats[3::2]:`

Comment: You can use `row.append(TbodyStats[i].text)` in the `for` loop, and then write the line after completion of the loop: `theWriter.writerow(row)`. In this case `row` is a list: `row = []`.

Answer (score 0):

Another method, For reference only.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc,utils,req
html = req.get('https://coronavirusbellcurve.com/')
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
specificDiv = doc.select('div.table-responsive-xl') # Get first div. If you want to get all divs, use this method: doc.selects('div.table-responsive-xl')
# TbodyStats = specificDiv.tbody.trs.selects('td|th').text # Get data
# TbodyDates = specificDiv.thead.trs.selects('td|th').text # Get date
data = specificDiv.table.trs.selects('td|th').text # Get all
rows = []
for row in data:
    rows.append(row[1:])
utils.save2csv('test.csv',rows)
```

Result:

```
5/5,5/6,5/7,5/8,5/9
1213260,1237960,1266822,1294664,1314610
24423,24700,28862,27842,19946
2.05%,2.04%,2.33%,2.20%,1.54%
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be able to do this (I can't test for sure because I don't have your exact data on hand):

```
row = []
for i in range(3, len(TbodyStats), 2):
    row.append(TbodyStats[i].text)
    if len(row) == 6:
        theWriter.writerow(row)
        row = []
```

I added the 'step' to your range so you don't have to use % for finding odd numbered indices, then just built each row until it hits 6 members, then flush that to the csv file, then empty the row so you can repeat the process.